# Swift 5 call function after scrollup UITable

Tags: swift, uitableview

I m implement view with UITableViewDataSource, now I need to call a method to refresh this UITable if the user scroll UP all the table as in Android system.
There is a way to call a method using swift 5 when the UITable when the user swipes his finger down and is at the beginning of the table?

regard

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIRefreshControl provided by Apple.

```
 // initializing the refreshControl
 tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

 // add target to UIRefreshControl
 tableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callPullToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
```

Add your code in callPullToRefresh() and it will be executed when the user will pull

```
    func callPullToRefresh() {
  // Do what you need for example fetchDataFromAPI()

  // Don't forget to dismiss the refresh control.
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.myScrollingView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
   }
```

For more information https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol